# iPad flip-clock with Core Animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-animation

I'm trying to make the flip-clock animation, I find this tutorial very interesting
http://www.voyce.com/index.php/2010/04/10/creating-an-ipad-flip-clock-with-core-animation/
but I still can't make it work.
 If someone did it and could share is experience or even the code source that will be really nice.

Thanks,

P.S: if you have other tutorial link please share them.

Comment: sorry i use the images to show like flip animation for showing timer

Comment: yes, its what I want. I wanna use images to display the timer too, not by clicking on the view everytime.

Comment: Interesting tutorial. I think the view detect touch up events to start the animation. Perhaps you could trigger the start of the animation using NSTimer in intervals?

Comment: Please provide more informations like what's exactly not working?

Comment: Im not good enough with Core Animation, so the tutorial at some point its not clear for me, there is some step missing I think. Nobody have the source?

Comment: have you made this animated clock? please reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What, exactly, do you need help on?

At the moment, there is some sample code available at Google Code:
http://code.google.com/p/idharmaclock/source/browse/trunk/LostoClock/Classes/LostoClockViewController.m?spec=svn2&r=2

Referenced from:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/tutorial-requests/52329-flip-clock-animation-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

check this out:

[Flip Transform](https://github.com/Dillion/iOS-Flip-Transform)

Answer (score 1):

I actually made a small framework out of the tutorial. Check:

https://github.com/jaydee3/JDFlipNumberView

It contains two main classes:

- `JDFlipNumberView` (animated digits)
- `JDDateCountdownFlipView` (a date countdown, just init with a date, set a frame and there you go.)

In any case, you just need to do three steps:

> 1. Init the class
> 2. Set a target value (or a date)
> 3. Start the animation

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can use this but who knows. There's a HTC hero theme for the iPhone, installable on jailbroken iPhones. This is not at all interesting, except for one feature of the theme. It has the flipclock. This theme shows the time on the homescreen exactly like you want. You can download the sourcecode of the theme [here](http://www.redmondpie.com/downloadscenter/HTC%20Hero%20Theme%20for%20iPhone/HTC%20Sense%20UI%20for%20iPhone%20-%20Modified%20by%20Taimur%20Asad.zip). You might have to dig into the code but the flipclock is there somewhere!
Good luck and I hope you'll be able to make your application work like a charm!

Comment: Thank u~~ but is all Javascript/HTML, I needed Objective-C code hehe thank u anyway~